# How to purposely return a NULL from TSQL query

Tags: t-sql, sybase

Is there a method to purposely return `NULL` from a TSQL query?

Comment: `SELECT NULL FROM ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to select it:

```
select NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sybase, but you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT CAST(NULL as int) AS NULLint --specify the appropriate datatype
```